# Duplicate class errors when building app larger than 150mb with Android App Bundles

Tags: unity, android, assetbundle

I have been trying to get Asset Bundles to work since my app is larger than 150MB, but the `Google -> Build Android App Bundle...` step keeps failing on me.

I am running Unity 2021.3.9f1
I tried both version 1.7 and 1.8 of the Google assetdelivery package, both broken.

I have 4 different errors. Has anyone dealt with these issues?

[image: Error messages]

Error 1:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
16 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 14 up-to-date

UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:178)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:BuildAndroidPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:179)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build (Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder,Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher/AppBundleBuildSettings) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:175)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:139)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndroidAppBundle () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:66)
```

Error 2:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetLocation found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackException found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackExtractionService found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackLocation found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManager found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackState found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStates found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ExtractionForegroundService found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.NativeAssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackErrorCode found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackStatus found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackStorageMethod found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:178)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:BuildAndroidPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:179)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build (Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder,Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher/AppBundleBuildSettings) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:175)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:139)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndroidAppBundle () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:66)
```

Error 3:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetLocation found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackException found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackExtractionService found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackLocation found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManager found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackState found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStates found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.ExtractionForegroundService found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.NativeAssetPackStateUpdateListener found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackErrorCode found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackStatus found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.model.AssetPackStorageMethod found in modules com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.asset-delivery-2.0.0:) and com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:) and com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.android.play.core-common-2.0.0:)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
16 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 14 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build(BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:178)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:BuildAndroidPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:179)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build(AppBundleBuilder, AppBundleBuildSettings) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:175)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build() (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:139)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndroidAppBundle() (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:66)
```

Error 4:

```
Build error: Build failed with 4 error(s)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (string,object[])
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.BuildToolLogger:DisplayErrorDialog (string) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/BuildToolLogger.cs:95)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:205)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:BuildAndroidPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:179)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build (Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder,Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher/AppBundleBuildSettings) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:175)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:139)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndroidAppBundle () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:66)
```

Comment: Android App Bundle and Asset Bundles are two different things.  Which are you trying to use?

Comment: It's a combination of the two. I am not having any issues creating Asset bundles in Unity.  This is the document I am following: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity#configure-assetbundles-ui. The issue happens on step 3 of Configure AssetBundles using the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Firebase unitypackage was causing conflicts with Google's App bundle deliver unitypackage.  I did not get to the bottom of the conflict, but I did remove the Firebase files and I was able to install and use the latest Play Asset Delivery (1.8.1 at the time of this writing).

Comment: Remember to mark this answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.